# How do I Install TWRP recovery in HTC 10

Tags: installation, twrp

Many people already did it but there are still who don't know how to do it and I am one of those. Am I able to do it by myself ??? Is it a long process ???
So please help me out.

Comment: What's wrong with the instructions [at the twrp.me download page](https://twrp.me/devices/htc10.html)?

Answer (score 0):

First of all it may seems to be complex steps to install a recovery in your phone. But, if we divide the process in certain steps, then it would be more clear to you. So follow my steps in order to Install TWRP Recovery on your HTC 10:

1. Unlock your phone with htcdev.com or s-off it with sunshine http://theroot.ninja (using built in temproot)
2. Flash latest twrp from http://twrp.me
3. Using adb, in twrp run - adb shell "echo KEEPFORCEENCRYPT=true>>/data/.supersu"
4. flash latest supersu from [http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps...v2-05-t2868133](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/2014-09-02-supersu-v2-05-t2868133)

If you want Video Tutorials of these steps, head over to this thread for your device: http://forum.xda-developers.com/htc-10/how-to/guide-root-optionally-s-off-radio-t3373025

Reply, if you need more help!

Comment: Thanks, Shashank that video tutorial is very useful and easy to understand.

Comment: Always, Sanjay.